# Compile Java in memory

Tags: java, dynamic, compilation, bytecode, execution

Is there a way to emit Java bytecode in memory and execute it?
I know that there's [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) class, but I'm asking something like `Reflection.Emit` of `.NET` platform.

Comment: the JavaCompiler class can be used to work entirely in memory (i wrote a libray to do this some years ago) not that it makes much difference.  ;-)

Comment: +1 @PeterLawrey, is this library open source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you check out the following

- [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/)
- [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)

Comment: +1 to both, one of this is exactly I need; now I've to spend some time to understand which API is simpler for my task (compile in memory a mathematical expression, for now)

Answer (score 1):

You need to play with the class loader to load dynamically some class. There are some interesting SO questions on the subject:

- [In memory jar / class file execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270871/317266)
- [How to load classes from jar file in-memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9964076/317266)

Answer (score -1):

This is possible but this requires the end user also to install `JDK`. Compile the bytecode to memory and create a new java process and start it. You can also execute `java source` directly.

See [`Beanshell2`](http://code.google.com/p/beanshell2/).